# python - Length of a list with the reduce() function

Tags: python, functional-programming, reduce

I need some help to count the numbers of elements in a list by using the reduce function.

```
def lenReduce(L):
  return reduce(lambda x: x + 1, L)
```

With this one I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Greetings from Berlin. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function argument to `reduce` takes two arguments: the return value of the previous call, and an item from the list.

```
def counter(count, item):
    return count + 1
```

In this case, you don't really care what the value of `item` is; simply passing it to `counter` means you want to return the current value of the counter plus 1.

```
def lenReduce(L):
    return reduce(counter, L)
```

or, using a `lambda` expression,

```
def lenReduce(L):
    return reduce(lambda count, item: count + 1, L)
```

Even though *your* function ignores the second argument, `reduce` still expects to be able to pass it to the function, so it must be defined to take two arguments.

Answer (score 4):

`lenReduce([5,3,1])`

returns `7`

What this means is, for the very first time when the lambda function is invoked, `count` is set to `5` and `item` is set to `3` which are the first two elemets of the list.  From the next invocation of the lambda function, `count` is incremented.  Therefore the solution does not work.

The solution is to set the count to a value of our choosing rather than the first element of the list.  To do that, invoke reduce with three arguments.

```
def lenReduce(L):
    return reduce(lambda count, item: count + 1, L, 0)
```

In the above call of reduce, `count` is set to `0` and item will be set to the elements of the list starting from index `0` on each iteration.

`lenReduce([3,2,1])`
outputs `3` which is the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

All previous answers seemed not work since it will add 1 to the **first element** of the given list every iteration. Try this **trick**, add 0 as the first element of the list, then decrease the return value by 1.

```
lenReduce = lambda L: reduce(lambda x, y: x+1, [0]+L, 0) - 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).